# How exclude files/folder from Maven outputDirectory

Tags: maven

I am developing maven project using Spring boot and JSF. According to [this](https://github.com/stephanrauh/JSF-on-Spring-Boot) example, the managed bean .class files should be put into /src/webapp/WEB-INF/classes directory, to be shown on JFS views. This is achieved by adding outputDirectory tag to pom.xml:

```
<build>
     <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>  
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                <target>${java.target.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But, I have noticed that except *.class files, there is also stored content of **src/main/resources** directory: i18n folder, templates folder, *.sql files, application.properties etc....

**My question:** How to exclude these unnecessary files/folders from /src/webapp/WEB-INF/classes directory?

Comment: Remove `outputDirectory` definition does not make sense.

Comment: If I remove outputDirectory, then  back-end data is not displayed on JSF views.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the file you dont want to the maven exludes.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
   <excludes>
     <exclude>**/src/main/java/myClassesToExclude*.java</exclude>
   </excludes>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of excluding files in Maven. I am pointing out the general ways here.

1. To exclude a resource, you only need to add an  element.

```html
<project>
  ...
  <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>[your directory]</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>[non-resource file #1]</exclude>
          <exclude>[non-resource file #2]</exclude>
          <exclude>[non-resource file #3]</exclude>
          ...
          <exclude>[non-resource file #n]</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

2. To include everything except the bitmaps, jpegs, and gifs, we can simply exclude them by:

```html
<project>
  ...
  <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.bmp</exclude>
          <exclude>**/*.jpg</exclude>
          <exclude>**/*.jpeg</exclude>
          <exclude>**/*.gif</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

3. You can also have both  and  elements. For example, if you want to include all text files that does not contain the word "test" in their filename.

```html
<project>
  ...
  <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.txt</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*test*.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

resource [maven.apache.org](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude from war file then use [warSourceExcludes] or [packagingExcludes] tag as :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>         
        <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/abc.xml,WEB-INF/pqr.xml</warSourceExcludes>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/abc.xml,WEB-INF/pqr.xml</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```